# How to cancel/not execute Bitbucket Pipelines builds based on a condition?

Tags: bash, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to update my yml file to ignore commits from certain users. Is this possible? Is there a similar solution? Ideally I wouldn't even want to trigger the build in the first place.

Pseudo code example of yml file (ignore syntax, I'm just showcasing what I'm trying to do)

```
user: git show -s --format='%ae' $BITBUCKET_COMMIT
unwantedUser: "person@mail.com"

pipelines:
  tags:
    '**' && user != unwantedUser: # any tags by wanted users
      - step:
          script:
            (...)
```

What would be the actual syntax to achieve that?

Answer (score 12):

I ended up including the `[skip ci]` string in my commit messages to avoid triggering the pipeline.

From the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-faq-827104769.html):

> Can I commit without triggering the pipeline? Yes. If you don't want
>   to run a pipeline on a commit that would normally trigger one, you can
>   include [skip ci] or [ci skip] anywhere in your commit message of the
>   HEAD commit. Any commits that include [skip ci] or [ci skip] in the
>   message are ignored by Pipelines.

Comment: That's causing an issue when merging PRs using Squash, where it'll also skip ci for the merged pipeline as the auto-generated comment includes the previous commits' messages

Comment: Good point, and another good reason to not use squash.

Comment: Squash should be used, and you should rewrite the commit message to omit [skip ci] when doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to trigger pipeline manualy you can use 'custom' tag.

From the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-pipelines-manually-861242583.html)

```
pipelines:
  custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
    sonar:
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "Manual triggers for Sonar are awesome!"
```

Custom pipelines do not run automatically on a commit to a branch. You can run a pipeline with commits view page or branches view page.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.